# RealM unable to save data with Nested Classes

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio, realm

I am using RealM for my project and unable to save a class with nested classes inside it. I am getting the following error in android studio.

```
RealmClass annotation does not support nested classes
```

here is what I am doing :

```
 public class Test extends RealmObject  {

    @SerializedName("1")
    @Expose
    private Leave leave;
    @SerializedName("2")
    @Expose
    private Today today;
    @SerializedName("3")
    @Expose
    private Vehicle cab;
    @SerializedName("4")
```

Gradle version of Realm is as follows :

```
compile files('libs/realm-android-0.84.2.jar')
```

Any help is will be very useful for me.

Comment: 0.84.2? Why.... ?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Just used the above version. What can use instead of this ?

Comment: If you are MinSDK 19, then you can use 3.0.0, otherwise I recommend 1.2.0

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I am using 14 as MinSdk thats why I am using 1.2.0. Thanks for ur suggestion man..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create your `RealmModel's` as standalone classes. Inner classes is not supported yet.
`@RealmClass` annotation is used, if your class can't extend of `RealmObject`. In this case your class also need to implement `RealmModel` interface.

Read more in [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#realmmodel-interface)